# Building docker image of Nuxt app with https

Tags: node.js, docker, https, nuxt.js

Recently, I've just changed my Nuxt app to support https with simple lines of code like bellow.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.cert'))
    }
  }
```

And I tried to build docker image for this app, of course, I've excluded server.key and server.cert.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Unexpectedly, building Nuxt app requires running nuxt.config.js file so it output follow error.

```
 FATAL  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/server.key'

  at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
  at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
  at nuxt.config.js:80:24
  at p (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:9442)
  at Object.loadNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js:1054:15)
  at loadNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:338:32)
  at NuxtCommand.getNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:463:26)
  at Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-build.js:90:30)
  at NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:413:22)
```

How can I dockerize my Nuxt app without including key files? I'd like to use docker volume when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create secret and use them on image. Here is how you can do it;
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/

Comment: What I want to do is passing keys on runtime not build time. Can docker secret solve this problem?